# Write crystals using mhchem properly

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

Usually I use the package `mhchem` for writing chemical formulas, but until now I was not able to find a solution for writing crystals such as `Nd^{3+}:YAG` properly with this package. When simply writing

```
\ce{Nd^{3+}:YAG}
```

it results in an error. My current alternative solution is to write it as

```
\ce{Nd^{3+}}:\ce{YAG}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Why place the `YAG` part into a `\ce` in the first place? `YAG` is not a chemical formula but an abbreviation for yttrium aluminum garnet.

Comment: If you want to stick with putting the whole expression into a `\ce` command, you can add an extra pair of `{}` around the `:` as in `\ce{Nd^{3+}{:}YAG}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message reads

```
./test.tex:6: Package mhchem Error: Assertion failed: Unexpected input character. In case
(mhchem)                you think this is a bug, please contact the package
(mhchem)                author.
```

which gives a hidden hint to the solution. As this is a parsing error for `mhchem` escaping might help. The manual says

> If you want to escape parsing, for instance for a simple hyphen (that
>   should not become a bond), use `{...}`.

And indeed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{Nd^{3+}{:}YAG}
\ce{Nd{:}Y3Al5O12}

\end{document}
```

[image]